# Grails validation dependent on other attributes

Tags: grails, grails-validation

What is the correct way to do something like this with grails:

```
class myDomainThing {
  String description
  MyOtherDomainThing otherThing

  static constraints = {
    description(nullable:if(otherThing))
    otherThing(nullable:if(description))
  }
}
```

So I either want there to be a link to the otherDomainThing or I want a String description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use Grails custom validation using the 
[validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)

```
static constraints = {
  description(validator: {
        return otherThing and !description
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use a custom validator

```
static constraints = {
  description validator: { val, obj -> 
     if(otherthing && val) {
         false
     }
     else {
       true
     }
  }
}
```

obviously some pseudocode in there around `otherthing`